# Why would TinyMCE6 delete content inserted via API (mceInsertContent called from a Chrome Extension)?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, tinymce

In an instance of TinyMCE6, used in the Brightspace LMS, calling the 'mceInsertContent' API inserts the desired text, but then the text is immediately deleted and the cursor moved to the beginning of the text entry area.
This behavior is not repeated in other instances of TinyMCE6 on this platform or my testing instances of TinyMCE6. For instance, I experience the problem is the "overall feedback" page shown in the video (link below), but not discussion responses.

I realize it is impossible for other users to reproduce this problem because they don't have access to this specific instance of TinyMCE. However, I'm hoping someone might see how the behavior could be possible and provide some guidance.

My Chrome Extension's content script it appends a simple script to insert HTML content and it works like a charm:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.textContent = "console.log('AP talks to tinyMCE1...'); tinymce.activeEditor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, " + JSON.stringify(request.sValue) + ");tinymce.activeEditor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, ' - just more.')";
(document.head||document.documentElement).appendChild(script);
script.remove();
```

When it's run from my Chrome Extension I get the correct inserted text the first time, then the add/delete/focus behavior on the second insert, then a correct insertion on the third instance and so on. In the video notice how the HTML is added, then removed (!!!)

[Short video illustration of issue](https://youtu.be/rOlJhxfq54c)

I can run this snippet from the page's console and the text is added correctly every time. I think this is more to do with the specific webpage, though, since if I insert text using my Chrome Extension, then click into a different field, then click into the TinyMCE editor and again use my Chrome Extension, things work as expected. In other words, changing focus somehow resets the editor's behavior.

Any ideas or hacks appreciated!

Comment: Apparently the page script ignores the changes in the code editor and overwrites them. Try document.execCommand, [example](/a/57900849).

Comment: Thanks for reading and suggesting. I have special code for TinyMCE because simpler inserts don't work with that editor. Were you thinking the execCommand would be added as a script? Or just run in the content script? It doesn't seem to have an effect inside TinyMCE.

Comment: I guess you need to focus a different DOM element inside the editor's DOM.

Comment: Thanks mucho. The TinyMCE editor is sensitive to any change and resets on every second insert/paste/append. Since it doesn't happen in my TinyMCE6, or even other instances in this solution, I'm going to chalk it up to a bug or unintended issue created by their implementation on this page.